# How to get realplayer file information?

Tags: c#

Is there a DLL or a way to get realplayer file info, such as duration, title, artist etc ?

Answer (score 0):

http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en Use Media Info ,i think there are some Bindings for C# .
U can Import a DLL ,or you can start as a Process and Store the Process.Standardoutput to a Stream after that Filter with String.Split or a Regular Expression .